# Values are not populating in the Form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Using VB.Net (Windows Application)

In the form (called as FirstForm), i am using textbox, add-form Button, search button.

When i click the add-form button, it will give the new form (same as FirstForm)

Code for adding new form

```
 Private Sub btnadd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnadd.Click
        Dim SecondForm As New FirstForm
        SecondForm.Show()
    End Sub
```

Search Button Code

```
Private Sub Search_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Search.Click
     If FirstForm.Focus = True Then
                FirstForm.textbox1.Text = gridview1.Rows(crRow).Cells("code").Value.ToString().Trim()
            Else
                Dim SecondForm As New FirstForm
                SecondForm.textbox1.Text = gridview1.Rows(crRow).Cells("code").Value.ToString().Trim()

            End If
End Sub
```

The above code is working, but If i am in second Form when i click the search button and selected the value, then the value is appearing in the FirstForm textbox, it is not appearing in the SecondForm textbox.

If SecondForm is showing, the selected Value should appear in the SecondForm textbox not in the FirstForm Textbox.

How to solve this issue.

Need Vb.net code Help

Comment: Can you show the code that gets called by the search button?

Comment: can you show some code for the search button?? if you are on the second form, it should be working there.. unless it is static or something like that..

Comment: I am a C# guy, so not sure what your is doing but instead of Form1.Focus try Form1.Active. It may solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Me` - Reference variable which hold ref. of current form.

```
 Dim frm As FirstForm
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If IsNothing(frm) OrElse frm.IsDisposed Then
            frm = New FirstForm
        End If
        frm.Show()
 End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
   Me.textbox1.Text = gridview1.Rows(crRow).Cells("code").Value.ToString().Trim()      
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am getting error as "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll"

Comment: You are creating two or more instances of **FirstForm** and you want to have (access) the members of current object. That's why **Me** is must.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Search Button (Button 2 as you mentioned in your sourcecode) is opening in the new form with Grid. I already mentioned in the source code like this "FirstForm.textbox1.Text = gridview1.Rows(crRow).Cells("code").Value.ToString().Trim()" .  Now How can i give Me.textbox1.Text

Answer (score 0):

Using "me" will not solve the problem?? why are you referring to the form in a static way?

```
Private Sub Search_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Search.Click
     textbox1.Text = gridview1.Rows(crRow).Cells("code").Value.ToString().Trim()
End Sub
```

Comment: @Gopal that code doesn't solve the problem? if the search button lives in a form, why are you just not referring to the form itself? this sounds more like a coding problem that anything.